Twisted Torus as 2-cells attached to path connected space?
I was wondering is it possible to construct the following twisted torus by attaching 2 cells to some path connected space?
I am trying to solve a problem involving Van Kampen Theorem:
Let $X$ be the space obtained as the quotient of a cylinder by identifying two boundary circles via $z\mapsto z^2$. And find fundamental group of $X$.
I want to use the following proposition given in Hatcher:

The inclusion $X\hookrightarrow Y$ induces a surjection $\pi_1(X,x_0)\to \pi_1(Y,x_0)$ whose kernel is generated by $N$. Thus $\pi_1(Y)\cong \pi_1(X)/N$.

Where $X$ is path connected and $Y$ is obtained by attaching a collection of 2 cells $e_\alpha$ via some identification maps $\phi_\alpha:S^1\to X$. If $s_0$ is a base point in $S^1$ then $\phi_\alpha$ determines a loop in $X$. Choose a base point $x_0\in X$ then a path $\gamma_\alpha$ connecting $\phi_\alpha(s_0)$ from $x_0$ makes $\gamma_\alpha \phi_\alpha \overline{\gamma}_\alpha$ into loops at $x_0$. And $N\subset \pi_1(X,x_0)$ generated by all the loops $\gamma_\alpha \phi_\alpha \overline{\gamma}_\alpha$.
Is it possible to solve the question by applying this proposition over here? I am having trouble constructing the space X in the problem by attaching 2 cells. Or is this proposition not applicable here?
I tried to construct the space by following how one would construct a torus by attaching 2 1-cells to a point and then attaching 2 2-cells to the circles but just changing one identification map to $z\mapsto z^2$. But this doesn't seem reasonable as gluing two boundary circles of a cylinder together.
If above construction is correct here are my idea on how to solve the problem:
Let $X^1$ be constructed by attaching two 1-cells to a point.(So, $X^1$ is basically $ S^1\wedge S^1$) Now, attaching 1 2-cell to $X^1$ via $z\mapsto z^2$. I have $X=X^2$ which is the quotient space of $X^1\sqcup D^2/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the relation induced by the identification. So, by the fact stated above the inclusion map $X^1\hookrightarrow X$ tells me
$$\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(S^1\land  S^1)/N= \mathbb{Z}* \mathbb{Z}/N$$
Where $N=<\gamma\eta^2\overline{\gamma} ~|~ $where $\eta$ is a loop in $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}>$.
Thanks!

I don't understand why you don't think this is reasonable. I see no problem, save for the fact that you should be attaching one 2-cell, not two (both for this construction and the standard CW-structure of the torus).

@BenSteffan Thank you, I read the CW complex definition incorrectly. Since the construction is correct, the fundamental group must be $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/N$ where $N$ as described as above. But I don't see what this group is exactly.

This is actually a semi-famous group, with the name $BS(2,1)$, it has two generators and one relator.

Your description of how to construct $X^1$ from $S^1 \wedge S^1$ is wrong, it's not obtained by "attaching a 2-cell via $z \mapsto z^2$.
One way to think of this is to first examine how the cylinder $S^1 \times [0,1]$ is attached to the $\eta$ loop: $S^1 \times \{0\}$ attaches via the map $\eta$; and $S^1 \times \{1\}$ attaches via the map $\eta^2$. But notice: the boundary orientation on $S^1 \times \{0\}$ goes the opposite direction of the $S^1$ parameter.
Now, to get the extra loop of $S^1 \wedge S^1$ --- the first loop named $\eta$ and the extra loop named $\gamma$ --- slice the cylinder $S^1 \times [0,1]$ along the path $\gamma = \{p\} \times [0,1]$ where $p = 1+0i$ is the base point of $S^1 \subset \mathbb C$. The cylinder itself gets sliced into a disc, and the boundary of that disc is attached via the path $\gamma\eta^2\bar\gamma\bar\eta$. The bar on top of $\bar\eta$ accounts for $S^1 \times \{0\}$ going the opposite direction of the $S^1$ parameter (this is very analogous to how the torus relator $\gamma \eta \bar\gamma \bar\eta$ is derived).
So you can present this group in generators and relators as
$$\left< \gamma, \eta \mid \gamma \eta^2 \bar\gamma \bar \eta \right>
$$
which means exactly the same thing as $\left<\gamma,\eta\right> \bigm/ \left<\!\left< \gamma \eta^2 \bar\gamma \bar \eta \right>\!\right> = (\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z) / N$ (one should be careful to use double brackets for normal generation, rather than the single brackets you used in your post for $N$).
In general, getting a presentation like this is pretty much the best you can hope for. But as said in the comments this turns out to be an interesting and pretty well known group, the first of the solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups.
